# Migrating a SharePoint database to another database

Tags: sharepoint

I want to make the SharePoint server to point to a  different content database other than the database it is pointing now.

Comment: You want do this by script or by server side code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the stsadm command below:

```
    stsadm –o addcontentdb –url http://yoursiteurl –databasename your_content_db –databaseserver target_SQL_server
```